# i want to sort json array based time

Tags: jquery, json

My question is about sorting using time and date.

This is my array object:

```js
[
    {
       exercise_description:"SDA",
       exercise_id:"13",
       exercise_name:"WEIGHT",
       exercise_time:"09:30 AM",
       workout_date:"2016-02-15",
       workout_desc:"SAMPLE"
    },
    {
       exercise_description:"SDA",
       exercise_id:"13",
       exercise_name:"ASA",
       exercise_time:"09:30 AM",
       workout_date:"2016-02-15",
       workout_desc:"kk"
    },
    {
       exercise_description:"dsf",
       exercise_id:"14",
       exercise_name:"vajrasanam",
       exercise_time:"03:45 AM",
       workout_date:"2016-02-15",
       workout_desc:"rfsgfrds"
    },
    {
       exercise_description:"fds",
       exercise_id:"12",
       exercise_name:"fsdd",
       exercise_time:"01:15 PM",
       workout_date:"2016-02-16",
       workout_desc:"dda"
    }
]
```

I want to sort this,like

```
[
    {
       exercise_description:"dsf",
       exercise_id:"14",
       exercise_name:"vajrasanam",
       exercise_time:"03:45 AM",
       workout_date:"2016-02-15",
       workout_desc:"rfsgfrds"
    },
    {
       exercise_description:"SDA",
       exercise_id:"13",
       exercise_name:"WEIGHT",
       exercise_time:"09:30 AM",
       workout_date:"2016-02-15",
       workout_desc:"SAMPLE"
    },
    {
       exercise_description:"SDA",
       exercise_id:"13",
       exercise_name:"ASA",
       exercise_time:"09:30 AM",
       workout_date:"2016-02-15",
       workout_desc:"kk"
    },
    {
       exercise_description:"fds",
       exercise_id:"12",
       exercise_name:"fsdd",
       exercise_time:"01:15 PM",
       workout_date:"2016-02-16",
       workout_desc:"dda"
    }
]
```

How can I sort this?

Comment: Which language do you want to use?? c#, JQuery, java??

Comment: jquery is better for me

Comment: ok and is the sort dependent on both exercise_time and workout_date properties?

Comment: ok give me some time. Ill be right back

Comment: jQuery isnt a language...

Comment: @StenMuchow I thought it is a scripting language. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: jQuery is a lib, Javascript is a language...

Comment: Hmmm sounds right. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

So I feel this must do the trick.

```
  var  arrayData =  [ 
 { exercise_description:"SDA", 
 exercise_id:"13", 
 exercise_name:"WEIGHT",
 exercise_time:"09:30 AM",
 workout_date:"2016-02-15", 
 workout_desc:"SAMPLE" 
 }, 
 { exercise_description:"SDA",
 exercise_id:"13", 
 exercise_name:"ASA",
 exercise_time:"09:30 AM",
 workout_date:"2016-02-15", 
 workout_desc:"kk" 
 }, 
 { exercise_description:"dsf",
 exercise_id:"14", 
 exercise_name:"vajrasanam", 
 exercise_time:"03:45 AM", 
 workout_date:"2016-02-15",
 workout_desc:"rfsgfrds" 
 }, 
 {
exercise_description:"fds",
exercise_id:"12",
exercise_name:"fsdd",
exercise_time:"01:15 PM",
workout_date:"2016-02-16",
workout_desc:"dda"
}
];

 //this must sort the array as you requested
 var sortedData = arrayData .sort(function(a,b){  
          return new Date(a.workout_date  + ' ' +  a.exercise_time) - new Date(b.workout_date  + ' ' +  b.exercise_time);
     });
```

make sure you check this logic with as many sets of data as you can to make sure this is stable.

Answer (score 0):

In JS dates can be problematic cross browser, [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) somes to the rescue with a simple [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

```
var sorted = unsorted.sort(function(a,b) {
  var aDate = moment(a.workout_date + ' ' +a.exercise_time).unix();
  var bDate = moment(b.workout_date + ' ' +b.exercise_time).unix();

  if(aDate < bDate) {
    return -1;
  }

  if(aDate > bDate) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;

});
```